# Is there a way to run robot framework tests on a remote machine using RIDE?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I would like to run the tests using the RobotFramework IDE and view the execution log on my machine but perform the actual tests on a remote machine, preferably without rewriting the test suites (or with minimal rewrite). The way I see it is some kind of mode or settings where you run the IDE on your computer but it connects to a remote "robotframework server" to launch the tests.

Is that easily achievable?

Comment: Maybe look at this? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface

Comment: This could be an option, although if I get it right it seems to be directed to executing a set of keywords remotely, whereas I'd like to execute the whole run (including the standard library keywords and preferably without changing all library references every time I want to switch from local to remote execution...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a local IDE but run the scripts remotely, then I can certainly recommend [RED](https://github.com/nokia/RED). This editor has a conveniently named [Remote Debug feature](https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/red_help/user_guide/remote.html.md) The linked documentation will explain more on the working of it.

High level, it does not require any changes to your scripts. It does require the set of scripts on the server and local to be in Sync.

Comment: Something definitely worth looking into, but unfortunately it would require a lot of convincing to use something other than the tool our department has settled for. Launching scripts remotely and from eclipse (which is already in our toolset) with debugging would be an option but there would be other aspects to consider. If there's a way to do it using RIDE and it's not too convoluted, we'll probably stick to it.

Comment: @NotGaeL If Eclipse is not an issue for your department, then RED will work for you as you can download the functionality from the Eclipse Market Place. Should connectivity to the Marketplace be an issue then the RED feature can be downloaded separately from GitHub and installed manually. Sadly I've not found an alternative for RIDE. A generic alternative is https://github.com/xyb/robotframework-debuglibrary/ but this will move you away from RIDE to a regular shell.

Comment: Yeah, like I mentioned I already have my team using RED. It is in our toolset for designing and implementing test suites. But for those running those tests over and over I think the tool should be RIDE, if possible.

Comment: Sorry @NotGaeL didn't quite understand the situation like that you have Script Developers working in RED and Script Users working in RIDE. Can you elaborate on what the Script Users do in RIDE? Would using Jenkins as a central server kicking off the scripts and displaying the log be of use to you?

Comment: I simply mean developers can (and do) make use of RED and RIDE, as they please when designing and implementing the suites and their test cases, as well as common libraries and resources. RIDE has some advantages for any user who simply wants to run the suites and report results, no matter the technical expertise of whoever is performing the validation. A remote setup should be available for both RIDE and RED users or any other IDE user, as long as the IDE has some kind of support for this "Robot Framework server remote API". That's what I am going for, if something like that exists.

Comment: Ideally I load any suite in RED or RIDE or whatever IDE and I config a remote robot framework server and when I run the tests what I see on the log screen is the output of the test currently running on the remote machine. In case I am not being clear enough: IDE independent remote test execution is what I am looking for. I could settle for a remote test execution that requires RIDE, but not one that's only available in RED.

Comment: Implemented solution: Run via remote desktop connection during development and Jenkins task when stable (scheduled/triggered via hook on commit). We improved traceability and avoided individual setups/testbenchs per tester/developer. Jenkins tasks were fairly easy to set up. Jenkins metrics are quite useful, easily customizable. Testers get a mail when execution fails so they can take the reports, investigate and open a ticket if necessary.